# Trichotomy law in ordinals

Tags: set-theory

Let $TOrd(x) \equiv Tr(x) \land \forall y\in x. Tr(y)$., where Tr means transitivity of a set. (every element is a subset)

It is easy to prove such facts:
$$TOrd(x)\rightarrow TOrd(Succ(x))$$
$$TOrd(A)\land TOrd(B)\rightarrow TOrd(A\cap B)$$
$$TOrd(x)\land (y\in x)\rightarrow TOrd(y)$$
$$TOrd(A)\land B\in A \rightarrow B\subsetneq A$$
Now my aim is
$$TOrd(A)\land Tr(B) \land B\subsetneq A \rightarrow B\in A$$
Question: How to prove trichotomy law for TOrd? (in below form)
$$(TOrd(A)\land x\in A \land y\in A) \rightarrow (x\in y\lor x=y\lor y\in x)$$
I tried the proof from [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Transitive_Set_is_Proper_Subset_of_Ordinal_iff_Element_of_Ordinal), but unfortunately it refers to linear ordering of elements of A, which is not proved on that stage, so attempt looks like using self-reference.

Answer (score 1):

The definition of an ordinal as a transitive set of transitive sets requires the axiom of regularity, so it is expected that somewhere in your endeavors you're going to encounter some kind of $\in$-induction.

For example here. We want to prove that if $TOrd(A)$ then for any transitive proper subset $B$, $B\in A$.

So suppose that's true for all $a\in A$, and let $B$ be a transitive proper subset. We can take some $x$ which is $\in$-minimal in $A\setminus B$. If $B\subseteq x$, then either we have equality and so $B\in A$, or by the induction hypothesis $B\in x$ and by transitivity also in $A$.

So suppose this was not the case. Take $y$ which is $\in$-minimal in $B\setminus x$. But by minimality, each $z\in y$ is also in $x$. So we can apply the same logic as before, either $x=y$ or $y\in x$. Oops, neither case is possible! So no such $y$ exists and we are done.

Comment: Apologies if there is something unclear. I am typing from my phone in the throes of a migraine.